# Converting turtle to json in java

Tags: java, json, json-ld, apache-jena, turtle-rdf

I'm trying to parse turtle format data into json format. I've searched about Apache Jena, but it's still clear if Jena is the solution.

Is there any Turtle parser already implemented in Java that allows me do this job?

Comment: Apache Jena has a command "riot" that runs a parser (Turtle and all other standard formats) and outputs in various formats, JSON-LD included. See http://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/#command-line-tools

Comment: This post shows how to use [rdf4j in combination with jsonldjava to create nice JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638342).